# Restructuring xml by using only one struct type for marshal/unmarshal-ing in go

Tags: xml, go

Say I have following block of xml data.

```
  <Result>
      <person>
          <name>Dave</name>
      </person>
      <id>
          <number>1234</number>
      </id>
  </Result>
```

and I want to restructure it to following.

```
  <Restructured>
      <Person>Dave</Person>
      <Id>1234</Id>
  </Restructured>
```

But only using one struct to do it. Is it possible?

Attaching code below.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Result struct {
    Person string `xml:"person>name"`
    Id     int    `xml:"id>number"`
}

type Restructured struct {
    Person string
    Id     int
}

const data = `
<Result>
    <person>
        <name>Dave</name>
    </person>
    <id>
        <number>1234</number>
    </id>
</Result>`

func main() {
    v := Result{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    newV := Restructured{Person: v.Person, Id: v.Id}

    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(newV, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(output)
}
```

I don't want to do it like this, allocating a new type of struct("newV") and copying field by field.
Is there any way to marshal automatically with different xml tags using original struct "v"?

Comment: Why (un)marshal at all? Parse the XML and output the new structure on the fly.

Comment: Just didn't want to parse XML by hand. My current xml data is way more complicated than the above example :).  So far seems like "parsing the xml by hand" or "using a second struct" is the only choice I have...

Answer (score 2):

Using a second struct is the most convenient way I see. If you don't want to make it exported, you can actually hide the other type inside your `MarshalXML`:

```
func (r *Result) MarshalXML(enc *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    type Restructured struct {
        Person string
        ID     int `xml:"Id"`
    }
    rr := &Restructured{Person: r.Person, ID: r.ID}
    return enc.Encode(rr)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/jZU2Jg0ZRZ.